# Child element above parent element on a small screen

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one nested inside of the other. According to the page design, the nested div needs to appear normally inside its parent on a large screen, [as in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1Vs9.jpg)

But on a small screen, the nested div needs to appear to be above the parent div, [as in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvhcL.jpg)

I don't want to position the child element absolutely, because it's a very poor and inflexible choice, especially for a responsive page.

HTML for divs / CSS for divs (on a large screen only):

```css
.container-div {
     background-size: 100% auto;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
     box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
}

.child-div {
     position: absolute;
     border: 3px solid white;
     width: 400px;
     height: 200px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="child-div">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code can't be what is show in the pictures: The child div is attached to the parent at the lower left corner. And the parent has no size here, and no content except the child div. Your real code must be different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inner-parent and flexbox.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
}

.inner-parent {
    background: red;
}

.child {
    background: blue;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    .parent {
        flex-flow: column;
        background: red;
    }
}


/* Reset and basic styles */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
    align-items: center;
    width: 200px;
}

.inner-parent {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="inner-parent">PARENT</div>
    <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

When smaller than 640px use `.inner-parent` as the lower div and use the real parent when larger than 640px by making it's background color match.  To fix the order just switch from `column-reverse` to `column` or just use `order` to change the order of just one of the child divs.